# Do Ferengi have any colonies outside their home system?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, ferengi

Aside from [Ferenginar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ferenginar), have the Ferengi ever settled or occupied planets from other systems in large numbers?

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Inhabited_planets#Ferengi_Alliance

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning but hasn't yet that the reason this question exists are various lines of dialogue about Ferengi woman not being allowed to travel off world.  (Which is in addition to not being allowed to own property, do business, or wear clothes.)  Now of course this is no way to set up a galactic franchise so generally everyone assumes Ferengi colonies exist with women that have traveled off world with their male owners.  But it is an assumption and really a necessary one because the alternative is silly.

Comment: @lucasbachmann- I always assumed male Ferengi settling on other planets got permission from the Nagus to take their women with them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes

The most clear canonical example is Lappa IV. From the [transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/172.htm) for "[Ménage à Troi](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/M%C3%A9nage_%C3%A0_Troi_(episode))" :

> WORF: When you have finished here, survey in that direction.
>
> CREWWOMAN: Aye, sir.
>
> GRAX: I wish I had some answers for you, Lieutenant Worf.
>
> WORF: Mister Homn was no help?
>   GRAX: None. He last saw them as he was leaving this clearing. When he
>   returned, all three of them were gone.
>
> DATA: Lieutenant Foley discovered this in the pond. (Tog's bouquet)
>   The species is Zan Periculi. It is not indigenous to Betazed, but to
>   Lappa Four. **A Ferengi world**.

There are several other examples, as list on the [list of Ferengi planets](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Inhabited_planets#Ferengi_Alliance)<sup>1</sup>, but they are more ambiguous. For example, Volchak Prime has ports that [are owned by Ferengi](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/411.htm):

> QUARK: Is something wrong?
>
> KRAX: You can't seat Turot next to Hoex. They've been bitter rivals
>   ever since Hoex bought out Turot's controlling interest in the cargo
>   ports on Volchok Prime.

However, this does not necessarily imply that the planet is under the control of the Ferengi alliance, merely that certain Ferengi do business there.

<sub>1. Credit to @Valorum</sub>

Comment: I'm not certain that being a "Ferengi world" is the same as being a colony. It might simply be a possession

Comment: @Valorum - One cannot really say. It seems exceedingly likely to me that a planet owned by the Ferengi also has significant Ferengi presence, but there is always some uncertainty.

Comment: Quark's cousin owns a moon.

Comment: @Valorum would a single Ferengi constitute a colony?

Comment: @xantec - I suspect there's a technical definition of what constitutes a colony *planet*, but my personal definition is that there has to be an intention to raise a self-sustaining population and the near total absence of other races.